# No module named 'Models', python 3.5.2

Tags: module, models, importerror, named

Got this Arkanoid clone code from internet however even after installing pygame binary still doesn' t want to work ("ImportError: No module named 'Models'"). I am using Spyder Python 3.5 and i cloned all repo from there https://github.com/Killavus/PyGame-Arkanoid

```
    import pygame
    import sys
    import math
    import random
    from pygame.locals import *


    import GameModule
    from GameModule.Models import *
    from GameModule.Constants import *

    class Game:
      def playSound( self, fileName ):
        sound = pygame.mixer.Sound(fileName)
        sound.play()

      def __init__(self):
        pygame.init()
        pygame.mixer.init(11025)


        self.actualState = states["START"]

        self.display = pygame.display.set_mode( gfx["screen"] )
        pygame.display.set_caption( "Arkanoid v" + version )
        # 4 basic objects, which define the game
        ## Painter - drawing actual situation on screen
        ## Mapper - loading the map
        ## Status - holding stance of the game: points, lifes, actual powerups etc
        ## Objects - holding actual game's objects: balls, bricks, pad etc

        self.objects = GameModule.Objects() 
        self.mapper =  GameModule.Mapper( self.objects )
        self.status =  Status()
        self.painter = GameModule.Painter( self.display, self.objects, self.status )
        self.lastState = None 
        self.fps = pygame.time.Clock()
        self.newLevel()

      def loop(self):

        self.fps.tick( gfx["framerate"] )
        for event in pygame.event.get():
          self.handleGlobalEvents( event )
          self.handleEvents( event )
        self.handleKeyboard()
        self.updateState()
        if self.actualState != states["GAMEOVER"]:
          self.painter.draw()
        else:
          self.display.fill( (0,0,0) )
          bigFont = pygame.font.SysFont( "sans-serif", 32 )
          gameOver = bigFont.render( "GAME OVER!", True, (255,255,255) )
          smallFont = pygame.font.SysFont( "sans-serif", 18 )
          points = smallFont.render( "Punktow: " + str(self.status.points), True, (255,255,255) )
          self.display.blit( gameOver, (gfx["screen"][0]/2 - gameOver.get_size()[0]/2, gfx["screen"][1]/2 - gameOver.get_size()[1]/2) )
          self.display.blit( points, (gfx["screen"][0]/2 - points.get_size()[0]/2, gfx["screen"][1]/2 - gameOver.get_size()[1]/2 - 40) )
        pygame.display.update()

      def handleEvents( self, event ):
        if self.actualState != states["PAUSE"]:
          if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_p:
              self.lastState = self.actualState
              self.actualState = states["PAUSE"]
              self.painter.paused = True
        else:
          if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_p:
              self.actualState = self.lastState
              self.painter.paused = False

        if self.actualState == states["START"]:
          if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_SPACE:
              self.actualState = states["PROGRESS"]
              (self.objects.balls())[0].speedChange( int( math.copysign( 5., float(self.objects.pad().lastMove) ) ), -5 )

      def handleGlobalEvents( self, event ):
        if event.type == QUIT:
          sys.exit()

      def handleKeyboard(self):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if self.actualState == states["PROGRESS"] or self.actualState == states["START"]:
          if pressed[K_LEFT]:
            if self.objects.pad().move(-10) and self.actualState == states["START"]:
              (self.objects.balls())[0].move(-10,0)
          if pressed[K_RIGHT]:
            if self.objects.pad().move(10) and self.actualState == states["START"]:
              (self.objects.balls())[0].move(10,0) 


      def updateState(self):
        if self.actualState == states["PAUSE"]:
          return
        if self.actualState == states["PROGRESS"]:
          self.objects.updatePowerups()
          for ball in self.objects.balls():
            speed = ball.speed()
            ball.move( speed[0], speed[1] )
            if ball.collideWithWall():
              pos = ball.pos()
              if pos[0] == 0 or pos[0] >= gfx["screen"][0] - ball.image.get_size()[0] - 1:
                ball.xInvert()
              if pos[1] == 0:
                ball.yInvert()
              if pos[1] >= gfx["screen"][1] - ball.image.get_size()[1] - 1:
                self.status.lives -= 1
                self.actualState = states["START"]
                self.playSound( "Resources/snd/chord.wav" )
                while len(self.objects.balls()) != 1:
                  self.objects.removeBall((self.objects.balls())[0])
                for powerup in self.objects.powerups():
                  self.objects.deletePowerup(powerup)

                self.objects.balls()[0].reset()
                self.objects.pad().reset()

            for obj in self.objects.grid():
              if ball.collision(obj):
                self.status.points += 100
                if obj.realx <= ball.position[0] and obj.realx + gfx["grid"][0] >= ball.position[0]:
                  ball.yInvert()
                if obj.realy <= ball.position[1] and obj.realy + gfx["grid"][1] >= ball.position[1]:
                  ball.xInvert()
                self.handleBrickCollision(obj)

            if ball.collision(self.objects.pad()):
              ball.yInvert()
              if self.objects.pad().position[1] <= ball.position[1] and self.objects.pad().position[1] + gfx["grid"][1] >= ball.position[1]:
                ball.xInvert()

          for powerup in self.objects.powerups():
            pad = self.objects.pad()
            if powerup.collision(pad):
              self.objects.deletePowerup(powerup)
              self.generatePowerup()
            if powerup.y == gfx["screen"][1] - 1 - powerup.image.get_size()[1]:
              self.objects.deletePowerup(powerup)

        if self.status.lives == 0:
          self.actualState = states["GAMEOVER"]
        if self.objects.grid() == []:
          self.status.level += 1
          if len(levels) == self.status.level:
            self.actualStatus = states["GAMEOVER"]
          else:
            self.newLevel()

        for modifier in self.status.modifiers:
          modifier[1] -= 1
          if modifier[1] == 0:
            if modifier[0] == "big_pad":
              self.objects.pad().setWidth(3)
              del modifier

      def generatePowerup(self):
        r = random.randint(1,3)
        # 3 possible powerups:
        # 1 - +1 life
        # 2 - for 30 sec the pad is larger
        # 3 - additional ball
        print (r)
        if r == 1:
          self.status.lives += 1
        elif r == 2:
          self.status.modifiers.append( [ "big_pad", gfx["framerate"] * 30 ] )
          self.objects.pad().setWidth(5)
        elif r == 3:
          ball = Ball()
          ball.position[0] = self.objects.pad().position[0] + (gfx["grid"][0]*self.objects.pad().gridWidth/2)
          ball.speedChange( int( math.copysign( 5., float(self.objects.pad().lastMove) ) ), -5 )
          self.objects.addBall(ball)

      def handleBrickCollision(self,obj):
        brickType = obj.getType()
        if brickType == "simple":
          self.objects.setGrid( obj.x, obj.y, None )
          rand = random.randint( 0, 9 )
          if rand == 9: # 1/10 chance for powerup
            self.objects.spawnPowerup( obj.x, obj.y )

        elif brickType == "solid":
          self.objects.setGrid( obj.x, obj.y, SimpleBrick(obj.x,obj.y) )
        elif brickType == "ghost":
          newType = random.randint( 0, 1 )
          if newType == 0:
            self.objects.setGrid( obj.x, obj.y, SimpleBrick(obj.x,obj.y) )
          elif newType == 1:
            self.objects.setGrid( obj.x, obj.y, SolidBrick(obj.x,obj.y) )

        self.playSound( "Resources/snd/ding.wav" )

      def newLevel(self):
        self.playSound( "Resources/snd/tada.wav" )
        self.mapper.load( self.status.level ) 
        self.objects.pad().reset() 
        while len(self.objects.balls()) != 1:
          self.objects.removeBall((self.objects.balls())[0])
        self.objects.balls()[0].reset()
        self.actualState = states["START"]

    class Status:
      def __init__(self):
        self.level = 0
        self.points = 0
        self.lives = startState["lives"]
        self.modifiers = []

    game = Game()

    while True:
      game.loop()
```